# Interpreter discrepancy in org-babel-python and python-mode

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-babel, python, babel

(Emacs version 26.1, Org version 9.1.9)

I have tried numerous solutions to get working in `org-mode` source blocks. [This solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33904/emacs-path-to-python-interpreter/33919#33919) works to change `python-mode` to utilize the Python3 interpreter, which I have installed in the local directory. I believe the *only* relevant part of my `config.org` file is as follows:

```
  (setq exec-path (append exec-path '("c:/users/chenry/appdata/local/continuum/anaconda3")))
  (setq python-shell-interpreter "c:/users/chenry/appdata/local/continuum/anaconda3/python.exe")

; more settings...

(with-eval-after-load 'org
    (org-babel-do-load-languages 
     'org-babel-load-languages 
     '(; other babel languages
       (emacs-lisp . t)
       (org . t)
       (shell . t)
       (sql . t)
       (C . t)
       (plantuml . t)
       (R . t)           
       (python . t))))
```

This works in `python-mode`, but not in `org-mode` python source blocks. I've also tried [this solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2415/17757), but I receive the Org-Babel Error Output:

> 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

For example:

[image]

Any advice for how I can make `python-mode` and `org-mode` Python interpreters consistent? Thanks!

Comment: @manandearth Works! Thank you! Added this to my init: `(setq org-babel-python-command "c:/users/chenry/appdata/local/continuum/anaconda3/python.exe")` If you move this to an answer, I'm happy to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the full path to python3 inside the double quotes `"foo/bar/baz/python3"`